# Travelling with a tagged Passport

Tags: uk, passports, dual-nationality, bahrain

My daughter has had a uk passport since birth (28 years) and applied to renew it. She also sent details of her Bahraini passport. After much fuss about names & the fact it was proved she cannot change the Bahraini names of her grandfathers, she has been told they will 'tag" her UK passport.

This means they will provide all the details of her Bahraini passport on her British passport.

My question is - because of this type of passport, will she not be open to racial abuse in foreign lands and also will a tagged passport be classed as a second class citizens passport?

I understand the need to know who has what passport but couldn't they have just put a code on her passport to recognise she has another passport & the details kept on file?

Comment: Which ‘foreign lands’ are you concerned about? Racial abuse is an offence in many countries.

Comment: Isn't it just a remark on the signature page where it says something like "the bearer of this passport is also known under the name of ..."?